# How can I change font / colors in mermaid.js Gantt

Tags: mermaid

I recently discovered mermaid.js which is great to design graphs and Gantts.
I'm using the live editor (https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/) and it's quite easy.
But how can I simply change the text font and its size, colors of the tasks in the editor ?
I've read that it's possible to do this changing css attributes, but that's not clear for me, I would need some more explanations.
Many thanks

Answer (score 12):

To change the border and background color of the nodes, text font and size for flowcharts, in "Mermaid configuration" panel, set the following code:

```
{
  "theme": "default",
  "themeVariables": {
    "nodeBorder" : "#004990",
    "mainBkg" : "#c9d7e4",
    "nodeTextColor" : "#274059",
    "fontFamily": "arial",
    "fontSize": "18px"
 }
}
```

For other changes, see the mermaid theming ref page:
https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/theming

Comment: It doesn't work for gantt diagrams, true. It works for other diagrams. I don't think it's possible to change font size for gantt diagrams.

Comment: See updated link to theming in my answer below (or above, depending on how you are sorting)

Comment: the link is not valid.

Comment: I think this was the inteneded link https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/theming still not working for fontsize in gantt

Answer (score 3):

For styling Gantt charts see the [Mermaid Documentation](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/gantt?id=styling).  However, since this method requires you to use a stylesheet I dont think that you can use it in the live editor.

More information on working with themes in general: [Documentation](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/theming)

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same issue and then found out that it needs to write in this way  for gantt chart.

```
    "gantt": {
      "fontSize": 18,
      "sectionFontSize": 20
  }
```